# Tailwind CLI and plugins not producing the correct transpiled CSS

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss

I'm using the Tailwind CLI to transpile some CSS and have issues getting postcss plugins to work with it.

The command I use is

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./assets/postcss/tailwind.css -o ./assets/dist/css/app.css
```

My app.css indeed gets produced.

Now the issue is that I use external plugins such as postcss-simple-vars, according to which I can use @variables inside my css. Tailwind CLI, knowing about this vars plugin thanks to its config, would logically transpile this (I also have issues with the mixin plugin, so it's not like it's limited to that only).

This is my tailwind.config.js (relevant part for plugins):

```
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('postcss-simple-vars'),
    require('postcss-mixins'),
    require('tailwindcss')
  ]
```

And this is my original tailwind.css:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@colorr: yellow;

body {
    background-color: @colorr;

}
```

Sadly, the produced app.css show the above exactly as is, meaning it does not transpile that part here about the variables. The import gets resolved though.

Same story with attempts at putting mixins in the css using the corresponding mixin plugin. It's like my plugins literaly get ignored.

My guess right now is that my CLI calls somehow ignore the plugins. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plugins` array in `tailwind.config.js` is for [Tailwind plugins](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins), which are distinct from PostCSS plugins.

For using PostCSS plugins with the Tailwind CLI:

1. Create a file to act as a PostCSS configuration file. Commonly, this file is called `postcss.config.js` (but can be any file name).
2. Add the PostCSS plugin array within the file:

   ```js
   module.exports = {
     plugins: [
       require('postcss-nested'),
       require('postcss-simple-vars'),
       require('postcss-mixins'),
       require('tailwindcss')
     ],
   };
   ```
3. Tailwind maintainers [recommend that you use their bundled version of their nesting plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting) for optimal compatibility:

   ```js
   module.exports = {
     plugins: [
       require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
       require('postcss-simple-vars'),
       require('postcss-mixins'),
       require('tailwindcss')
     ],
   };
   ```
4. [`postcss-mixins` recommend to have their plugin before `postcss-nested` and `postcss-simple-vars`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-mixins#postcss-mixins):

   ```js
   module.exports = {
     plugins: [
       require('postcss-mixins'),
       require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
       require('postcss-simple-vars'),
       require('tailwindcss')
     ],
   };
   ```
5. Pass the PostCSS flag to the Tailwind CLI command:

   ```
   npx tailwindcss -i ./tailwind.css -o ./app.css --postcss
   ```

   If you used a different file name in step 1, pass the PostCSS configuration file as the value for the flag:

   ```
   npx tailwindcss -i ./tailwind.css -o ./app.css --postcss path/to/postcss.configuration.js
   ```

Furthermore, you are using incorrect syntax for what I presume would be for a variable to be used via `postcss-simple-vars`. Variables are denoted by a dollar sign prefix (`$`), not at (`@`):

```css
$colorr: yellow;

body {
    background-color: $colorr;
}
```

[Full example with all plugins working available on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jyq2bn?file=input.css&view=editor).

Comment: Thanks, the solution was indeed to define the postcss plugins outside of tailwind. Sounds logical explained like that, but it did not occur to me that tailwind was not acting as a proxy for postcss.

So creating a dedicated postcss.config.js and adding the --postcss flag to the tailwind CLI does the trick. Of course, the plugins have to be installed as dev dependencies.

Also, I had a "brain fart" when it comes to using @ instead of dollar for the variables, as you have rightly pointed out. I'll put this down to tiredness.